# C# ignore certificate errors via config file

Tags: c#, web-config, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I know you can ignore certificate errors by using following line in your code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ( sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors ) => true;
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to do that via web.config file. Reason for that is b/c we can specify proxy server in web.config via defaultProxy and any HttpClient is going to use the proxy. The issue comes when we are specifying Fiddler as the proxy and enabling traffic decryption so we can debug calls to 3rd party services. However, in such cases we will get a certificate error which could be ignored by using that line but I would like to do it without recompiling our service.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore certificate errors? Don't you trust the issuer of the server certificate?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, as I wrote before: when Fiddler gets in the middle and decrypts the traffic you are going to get a certificate error b/c Fiddler's certificate is a local machine certificate and nothing trusts it. I want to ignore that error and process the call.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager
          checkCertificateName="false"
          checkCertificateRevocationList="false"
      />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

If you don't have  section in your web.config, simply add it.

Comment: At least in my case it doesn't work. I'm still getting certificate failures

Comment: This only skips certain certificate errors. It will not make .NET accept an invalid certificate.

Comment: My case too. It just works when certificate is revocated. It doesnot work in Self signed cert case.